# run a jdk1.4 compiled jar on jdk1.6

Tags: jar, java-6, jdk1.4

I want to run a jdk1.4 compiled jar on jdk1.6.
Will there be anything wrong about it.
JVM is forward compatible, so I think there will be no problem.
Is it true.

Comment: Yes there should n't be any problem. Did you try it ? Only the reverse  would not be possible.

Comment: You should always retest your code if you are altering how it is being run.

Comment: It is backward compatible, not forward compatible

Answer (score 0):

As of the Java byte code, the compiled code should be **backward** compatible with increasing JRE versions. This means that in general, a v6 JVM should be able to run code that is compiled with a v4 JDK. (While the JRE is backward compatible, the Java compiler is forward compatible, i.e. v4 source code is supposed to be compilable by a v6 compiler.)

However, you can run into problems with the libraries that the v4 code is compiled against when the code is run on a v6 JRE. You can find an overview of API changes from v4 to v6 on this [webpage](http://upstream-tracker.org/java/versions/jdk.html).